# onClick() function erased during build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile

When I build my game to Android, buttons stop calling the onClick() function I set in the Editor. In play mode and in simulator, all works well. The only way I can make the buttons work is to make a script which adds the onclick function to the button again on startup. Is there a way to fix this without having to write a script to add it to every single button? (Buttons in other scenes dont work either)